# Switch from NSDictionary to Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I have some code to get EXIF data from file, but it uses NS-Types. I like to get Swift 3 conform and use standard swift types like Dictionary or String. When deleting "NS", I get the error that ".value()" does not exist. And no hint by the compiler what is the new function call:

```
let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil)
let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource!, 0, nil)! as NSDictionary

let exifDict = imageProperties.value(forKey: "{Exif}") as! NSDictionary
let dateTimeOriginal = exifDict.value(forKey: "DateTimeOriginal") as! NSString
print ("DateTimeOriginal: \(dateTimeOriginal)")

let PixelXDimension = exifDict.value(forKey: "PixelXDimension") as! Double
print ("PixelXDimension: \(PixelXDimension)")

let exifDictTIFF = imageProperties.value(forKey: "{TIFF}") as! NSDictionary
// optional
if let Software = exifDictTIFF.value(forKey: "Software") as? NSString {
    print ("Software: \(Software)")
}
```

Any hint how to change it?

Additionally:
Using this

```
let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource!, 0, nil)! as Dictionary

let exifDict = imageProperties["{Exif}"] as! Dictionary
```

will deliver an error "Ambiguous reference to member 'subScript'" for the second row!

Comment: Just use key subscription `imageProperties["{Exif}"]`. Use never `valueForKey` to get a single value from a dictionary. But be careful: Casting `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex` to Swift `Dictionary` didn't work as far as I can remember. But this might be fixed in Swift 3.

Comment: Ok, so what can I do? I works fine with NSDictionary. And I like to have Dictionary.

Comment: Dictionary is a generic. You have to provide a type for example `Dictionary<String,Any>`

Comment: Wouldn't it be `as [String : Any]`, not `as Dictionary<String,Any>` ?

Comment: Yes, that does the job (as [String : Any]). Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually `Dictionary<String,Any>` and `[String : Any]` are synonyms.

Comment: Yes, good to remember. You're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All of the `NSDictionary` needs to be something like `[String:Any]`. And all of the `value` calls should use normal key access.

```
let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil)
let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource!, 0, nil) as! [String:Any]

let exifDict = imageProperties["{Exif}"] as! [String:Any]
let dateTimeOriginal = exifDict["DateTimeOriginal"] as! String
print ("DateTimeOriginal: \(dateTimeOriginal)")

let PixelXDimension = exifDict["PixelXDimension"] as! Double
print ("PixelXDimension: \(PixelXDimension)")

let exifDictTIFF = imageProperties["{TIFF}"] as! [String:Any]
// optional
if let Software = exifDictTIFF["Software"] as? String {
    print ("Software: \(Software)")
}
```

This code is terrible. All of those uses of `!` are a bad idea. Proper, safe unwrapping and casting should be used throughout this code.

Comment: Sure. This was the first draft. I always check for nil before accessing.